# Fresh install 12.04 from 11.04 can't log in

Tags: 12.04

Hi just did fresh install of 12.04. rsynced my /home to new partition prior to install. All went fine but I cannot log in with my user account. Am able to log in as Guest. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot log in"? Do you get an "incorrect password" error? Please provide more details.

Comment: no not password error, Unity attempts to load but there is a black screen with some output  that I cannot read as it returns to log on screen too quickly, I am currently logged on as Guest.

Comment: I am suspecting a compatability issue with some of the config in my home directory

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try to reset Unity and/or Compiz. There are useful instructions available here:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-reset-unity-launcher-icons-or.html

Another option is to try moving all the contents of you home folder somewhere else. You should be able to login with a "blank" used account. Then try to move things back to your home folder, one directory at a time. This should allow you to figure out what file/directory is causing problems.

Comment: I mean that if there is no content in your home directory, your account will be treated like it was just created. This should make it possible to login, and then salvage what files you actually need. If you do not copy any hidden files (.*) from your old home directory, it's very unlikely that it will fail.